# JavaScript: nonempty array treated as empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm developing a ReactJS app and have data stored in an array. The array is non-empty, but for some reason it insists that `arr[0]` is undefined and `arr.length` is 0.

Edit: here's the result of the following four lines:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.arr));
console.log(this.state.arr);
console.log(this.state.arr.length);
console.log(this.state.arr[0]);
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: A snippet would be helpful

Comment: The array is logged as a reference, so it will be updated in the console when it's updated in your code. You could try `console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))` to see what it looks like at the time of the logging.

Comment: In terms of a solution? I'm honestly baffled. I've tried `console.log(arr.length)` and `console.log(arr[0])` right after this and it's still no good. I can update the question with a screenshot of the output.

Comment: You see the *actual output at that time* in the logged line, it is `[]` ... an empty array

Comment: @Tholle yeah, looks like it is actually empty. I'm going to dig through my code and see what could be wrong but unfortunately there's too much code to post.

Comment: This happens when you try to access the array before it was populated, which means there is likely an async process and you try to access the array before that process finished.